# Can a Banach space and its dual both contain copies of $\ell_1$?

Tags: banach-spaces, dual-spaces, banach-lattices

Each AL space $E$ contains a copy of $\ell_1$. Its dual $E'$ is an AM space. Is it possible for $E'$ to contain a copy of $\ell_1$ as well?

Comment: AL space? AM space?

Comment: Are you asking about lattice isomorphic copies of $\ell^1$ ? If not, for any Banach space $X$ that contains an isomorphic copy of $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$,  $X^*$ contains an isomorphic copy of $\ell^1(\mathbb{R})$, see Proposition 3.3 in http://doi.org/10.4064/sm-30-2-231-246